# Capture Streamed Audio Into An Independent Client Software Like Cubase, Audacity, Logic Pro X, etc

Tags: audio, stream, recording, audio-capture

I want to get to know the process of capturing a live audio recording given it be a **voice recording of a person**, which then will be captured by any type of browser, say **Chrome**, and would be fed **live** into a sound recording software like **Cubase, Logic Pro X & Audacity.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you want to record realtime audio from the browser into a DAW?